# If app is active on Push Notification

Tags: iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

After I send a push notification I want the app to open on my inbox page so the user can see the new messages on the inbox. I have the following code in my AppDelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

    [self.tabController setSelectedIndex:2]; 
}
```

When I send a push message and the phone is active it goes straight there without warning. I know thats what it is supposed to do with my code but is there a way to change it like so

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

    if(app.isActive == FALSE)
          [self.tabController setSelectedIndex:2]; 
}
```

Any insight on this will help greatly. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt the code will run while the application will be inactive. So your If will always return NO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Stanislav Yaglo, [Objective C: How to check if application is currently active (i.e. user is using it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730531/objective-c-how-to-check-if-application-is-currently-active-i-e-user-is-using) :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        // For example, update the tab bar
    }
    else {
        self.tabController.selectedIndex = 3;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

You could set a bool to `YES` once you enter the application, simply set the bool in:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

and set the bool to `NO` in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell if the application was in the foreground by checking the applicationState like so:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
        // app is in the foreground
    else
        // app was just brought from background to foreground
    ...
}
```